# Google adword & Search console (google webmaster tools)

Tags: google-ads-api, google-search-console

I am a bit worried about my impression counts. I have linked my search console to adWords account. 
On Google AdWords account impressions are increasing day be day. Currently the Impressions on Google AdWord Account for a website are 17840 But in search Console it shows Impressions are only 12. 
I am too much worried about it. 
What to do to show correct impressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi There is a basic difference between google adwords Impression and Google webmaster impression. Google adwords shows that how many times your **Paid ad** is showing to user on any network like Search, display and youtube, it will not be counted by Google webmaster tool. Webmaster will show your organic search impression that how many times your website has been shown to user by google. Its a free practice. so

> adword will show your paid impression and webmaster will show you free

.